# One line VBA statement expression with If-else condition

Tags: vba, syntax

I am creating an VBA-like expression.

```
Replace([EmailAddress], "@domain.com", , , "", , )
```

`[EmailAddress]` is actually consist of a string, for example "john.doe@domain.com". So the result generated from the expression will be "john.doe"

I would like to set a condition where, if the result returned from the expression is more than 20 characters, the result return will be "john.d".

Basically remove all the characters behind the first character after the symbol "."

The idea is something like:

```
Variable a = Replace([EmailAddress], "@domain.com", , , "", , )

If len(a) > 20 then
  an expression that remove all the characters after the symbol "."         and first letter

else
  a

End if
```

I am not sure if I am making sense, as I am not a programmer and not sure if these VBA syntax used are correct. I think there should be a single line expression to accommodate all these conditions.

Really appreciate if someone can help to guide me.

Answer (score 0):

Below is a short VBA function that accepts an email address. If there is an "@" in there, it gets the text to the left of it. If this text is longer than 20 characters and has a "." in it, then get all of the text to the left of the ".", plus the "." and the next character.

```
Function fRemoveDomain(strDomain As String) As String
    If InStr(strDomain, "@") > 0 Then
        fRemoveDomain = Left(strDomain, InStr(strDomain, "@") - 1)
        If (Len(fRemoveDomain) > 20) And (InStr(fRemoveDomain, ".") > 0) Then
            fRemoveDomain = Left(fRemoveDomain, InStr(fRemoveDomain, ".") + 1)
        End If
    End If
End Function
```

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

This UDF should do the trick assuming the input of your email **always** follows the format where everything in brackets can be a string that does not contain `@` or `.`:

- `[name].[name]@[domain].com`

---

```
Public Function DOMAIN(Target As String) As String

If Len(Split(Target, "@")(0)) > 20 Then
    Domain = Split(Target, ".")(0) & "." & Left(Split(Target, ".")(1), 1)
Else
    Domain = Split(Target, "@")(0)
End If

End Function
```

---

### You can call your UDF right on the worksheet like so:

[image]

### Or from a macro like so:

[image]

---

---

You can also avoid using VBA altogether with

```
=IF(LEN(MID(A2,1,SEARCH("@",A2)-1))>20,MID(A2,1,FIND(".",A2)+1),MID(A2,1,SEARCH("@",A2)-1))
```

Comment: Thanks! I am close now, sorry my settings (MS Azure) can only accept VBA expressions. So I modified it into:
```
IIF(
Count(Mid([EmailAddress],1,inStr([EmailAddress],"@")-1))>20,
Mid([EmailAddress],1,inStr([EmailAddress],".")+1),
Mid([EmailAddress],1,inStr([EmailAddress],"@")-1)
)
```
The (only, hopefully) problem now is the syntax "inStr" doesn't accept +1 or -1 in the end. Tried to put the whole inStr....+1 in parentheses but doesn't work either.

Comment: My solution doesn’t use instr so no idea what you’re asking about. You may have commented on the wrong solution

Comment: InStr is the replacement for Search and Find in VBA, at least that is what I found.

Comment: Have you tried either of the methods I gave you lol both of the above methods are tested and working just fine. Not going to help with a 3rd way when I’ve already provided 2

Comment: Forgive me but I am not from a programming background, I am sysadmin trying to match certain attributes in Azure by creating VBA-like expressions. Azure can only accept VBA syntax and I can't force it to use others. Your first solution (if-else) cannot work, the system wouldn't accept If-else condition. I will try to find ways to fix the inStr because that is the closest to success so far, thanks for your kind help.

Comment: if-else is VBA syntax so i'm not sure what you mean. Your question is tagged with VBA so you got VBA answers. If you needed an answer in another language you should have tagged it with that language. Good luck!